# How to resolve this ‘Unresolved reference’ when I have defined the function?

Tags: kotlin

I am just a beginner in programming, started learning Kotlin today. I am getting this error.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val (two, three) = nextTwo(1) // Unresolved reference: nextTwo
    println("1, $two, $three")

    fun nextTwo(num: Int) : Pair<Int, Int> {
        return Pair(num+1, num+10)
    }

}
```

[Picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raBjX.png)

Comment: @Scooter  why answer if you do not know the topic?  Kotlin allows this, you will confuse the issue by guessing, even if the guess works.

Answer (score 7):

Local functions can only be used in their local scope after their definition.

You can either move the `nextTwo` function out of the `main` function, like this (in this case, it doesn't matter whether it's before or after `main`):

```
fun nextTwo(...) {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
    nextTwo(...)
}
```

Or you can just move it before its usages inside `main`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun nextTwo(...) {}

    nextTwo(...)
}
```